# Convert multiple column comma seperated string to json

Tags: c#

I have a following column in SQL table

```
column1 column2
12,13    abc,xyx
```

I am trying to convert to JSON from C#. I am getting a single row with comma separated in my ASP.Net MC. Not getting an idea how to proceed.

```
{
    "Details": [{
        "column1": "12",
        "column2": "abc"
    }, {
        "column1": "13",
        "column2": "xyx"
    }]
}
```

Comment: A SQL table in C# is simply a class. Make an object and serialize it to a json. Or provide more details bc this is somewhat unclear.

Comment: If possible, perhaps redesign your database so you're not storing multiple values in a column on a single row.

Comment: You will need to query your DB row and split it into values, store those values into an object that matches your JSON structure, and then serialize that object. You should heed the other warnings about redesign of your database. You're defeating the point of using a database if all the data is in a blob anyways.

Comment: As suggested, you ought to redesign your database. If you feel the need to store multiple values in a column, most likely you should have another related table with multiple rows related to each row in the existing table.

Comment: I don't have controll on Db I am getting the data as comma separated to my asp.net mvc controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  System.Text.Json

```
var model = new Model { column1 = "12,13", column2 = " abc,xyx" };            
        int countCol=model.column1.Split(',').Length;
        List<Model> m = new List<Model>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countCol; i++)
        {
            var cols1Values = model.column1.Split(',');
            var cols2Values = model.column2.Split(',');
            var f=new Model {
                column1 = cols1Values[i],
                column2 = cols2Values[i]
            };
            m.Add(f);

        }
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(m);
```

output above code in json = ***[{"column1":"12","column2":" abc"},{"column1":"13","column2":"xyx"}]***

Comment: I would advise against answering the serialization part because ASP.NET will handle this for you. Unless you return JSON text explicitly as a `JsonResult`, you'll potentially risk double serialization. That is to say: you manually serialize it, and then ASP.NET serializes the already-serialized string.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I wrote the sample conversion code in the console app
The programmer can use it anywhere according to the available commands

Comment: I wasn't complaining about your answer in general. I just see beginner programmers making the mistake of double serializing stuff with ASP.NET from time to time here on StackOverflow. It wasn't 100% a comment aimed at you, so much as the OP/other readers of the answer. I just hoped that it would help people avoid that pitfall.